# setxkbmap and xmodmap often stop working

Tags: bash, xmodmap, setxkbmap

I have a script to:

1. Set the keyboard layout to include accents
2. Set capslock as mod when held
3. Set capslock as escape when pressed

It looks like this:

```
setxkbmap -rules evdev -model evdev -layout us -variant altgr-intl &
sleep 1
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap &
sleep 1
killall -q xcape &
xcape -e "Hyper_L=Escape" &
```

Those `sleep` are there because otherwise it doesn't work well. I don't understand why and I'd love to. In addition to that, sometimes the escape part of it just stops working, and I have to relaunch the script. I'm not exactly sure what triggers this but it is annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams you get a race collision if you put every command in the background (`&` at the end of line). Delete these `&` and the commands will be executed one after the other.